# Can I use for loop in fillna()?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace `100 NaNs` into `1~100` in number.
so I think I can use fillna,

but I don't know

```
for i in range (1,101):
    df.fillna(i)
```

is working. does it work?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

If `df` is `pandas.DataFrame`:

```py
df.loc[df[col].isna(), col]=range(1,101)
```

For column `col` where you have these `nan`-s

If `df` is `pandas.Series`:

```py
df.loc[df.isna()]=range(100)
```

Comment: Thanks.
What if it's a series rather than a dataframe? sorry, I'm a complete novice at python.

Comment: No worries, it's similar then - I included option, when `df` is `pandas.Series`.

Comment: Thx very much. but I got this error message. -> "'range' object has no attribute 'loc'." Can you tell me how to solve it..?

Comment: Get rid of `s =` it should be only `s.loc[...]=...`

Answer (score 0):

what Grzegorz Skibinski suggested is actually for a series. Because every column in a dataframe can be treated as a series, according to me .I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, I see . Well sorry, Grzegorz Skibinski's method seems the best to me .